# What happens when you Intentionally cause a memory leak in C program while debugging in Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio, memory, malloc, free

Is the memory lost until a reboot or does VS have some safe-mechanism to handle that? I've always wondered...

Comment: How can you cause memory leak in VS? Do you have access to their source codes? The only way you can do it if you write faulty addon.

Comment: @Andrey It's pretty likely that Muli means "in a program started from Visual Studio". At least that's how I read it.

Comment: In modern OSs all processes are completely isolated from each other (in general). When a process dies, it's as if he never existed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The leaked memory will be freed when the process leaking the memory is closed and the operating system cleans up.

Comment: Thanks for not mocking unlike the other dudes.

Comment: @MuliYulzary nobody was really mocking you. Your original question was stated incorrectly and demonstrated certain misunderstanding.